# ReturnDatesAsStrings=>true returns timestamp with decimal & zeros

Tags: php, sql-server, fpdf, sqlsrv, phpspreadsheet

I'm using **PHP 7.2**, **MS SQL Server**, **fpdf**, and **phpSpreadsheet** to create PDF and Excel reports of my data. Initially I had trouble returning the timestamp (date) fields in the reports, but adding `"ReturnDatesAsStrings"=>true` in my *connection.php* solved that problem.

The issue now is that the date fields on the reports have a decimal and zeros added and show up as `2018-03-01 16:43:19.0000000`. How can I stop the addition of `.0000000`? I'm not sure if it makes it any more complicated that it also needs to work with **fpdf** and **phpSpreadsheet**, but I included that info just in case.

**UPDATE:** Zhorov's first answer was right. I removed `"ReturnDatesAsStrings"=>true` from *connection.php* and the phpSpreadsheet files work great! On the fpdf files, I had to add in '$date_as_string = date_format($data['created_date'], 'Y-m-d H:i:s');' and then the PDFs work too.

**FINAL SOLUTION:** NULL values were causing a problem, but Zhorov's fix worked. Had to add `$date_as_string = is_null($row['DateField']) ? '' : date_format($row['DateField'] , 'Y-m-d H:i:s');`

Comment: Can you try with three separate $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$row , some_value); calls. See updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ReturnDatesAsStrings => false` connection option and `date_format()` PHP function.

When `ReturnDatesAsStrings` is `false`, `datetime`, `Date`, `Time`, `DateTime2`, and `DateTimeOffset` types will be returned as PHP Datetime types. So format these fields as PHP dates with custom format.

```
<?php

# Connection
$server = 'server\instance,port';
$cinfo = array(
    "ReturnDatesAsStrings"=>false,
    "Database"=>'database',
    "UID"=>"uid",
    "PWD"=>"pwd"
);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $cinfo);
if( $conn === false )
{
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_connect): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}

# Statement
...
$sql = 'SELECT [DateField] FROM [Table]';
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);  
if ($stmt === false) {
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_connect): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $date_as_string = is_null($row['DateField']) ? '' : date_format($row['DateField'] , 'Y-m-d H:i:s');

    # I'm not familiar with PhpSpreadsheet, but based on documantation, this should work.
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$row , $data->OBJECTID);
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$row , $data->Inspector);
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$row , $date_as_string);

    echo $date_as_string;
    echo '</br>';
}
...

# End
sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
sqlsrv_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: If I do sqlsrv_fetch_array instead of sqlsrv_fetch_object, the error says "Trying to get property 'OBJECTID' of non-object..."

Comment: removing the "ReturnDatesAsStrings"=>true from the db connection FIXED the problem with the excel report! So now all I have to do is use your date_format code in the fpdf and everything works!!

Comment: do you know why this would work on a timestamp field, but not a regular date field? When I try to insert other date fields (where the dates have been input via a date picker) it tells me "Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string." But if I use "ReturnDatesAsStrings"=>true it will work, but will add the .0000000 again.

Comment: I think it has something to do with NULL values in those fields.

Comment: @KVarney See updated answer with check for null DateTime objects. May be this will help. This will work for all datetime fields.

Answer (score 1):

Not a PHP guy, but in SQL Server, you can convert your datetime values to a **string**.

**Example**

```
Select ViaConvert = convert(varchar(19),getdate(),120)
      ,ViaFormat  = format(getdate(),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
```

**Returns**

```
ViaConvert             ViaFormat
2018-09-13 09:35:12    2018-09-13 09:35:12
```

---

**Please Note:** Just a warning, `format()` has some great features, but it not known as a performer.